# CE certification of new project Radio Equipment Directive

Tags: bluetooth, emc, ce, regulations

I work at a certification Institute of construction products, but sometimes we do consultancy on other related products. Recently, a manufacturer asked us a regulatory/certification study on his new project.

The project basically consists on an Arduino (CE certified) with a Bluetooth/Wifi module (also CE certified ESP32-S2-SOLO), an 240V/12V adapter/charger (CE certified), a 12V solenoid valve (not certified) and tubes/pipes for domestic application in irrigation.

I know that CE mark is not required for pipes and solenoid valves under Construction Products Regulation (CPR) (305/2011) nor the Pressure Equipment Directive (PED) (2014/68/EU).

But I'm not sure about the electrical/electronic parts as our expertise is focused on construction products.

My conclusions so far are:

- His product falls under the scope of the RED, as it is a radio equipment. According to this directive (paragraph 7 and 8), the Directives of Low Voltage (2014/35/EU) and EMC (2014/30/EU) should not apply to radio equipment (because the RED already covers both Directives). And since the CPR and PED also don't apply to this product either, I assume only the RED is applied. (unclear about the role of the charger here).
- Thus, the harmonized standards to provide a presumption of conformity with the essential requirements of this directive for this product that I've found are:
- Art.3.1a Health & Safety:

  - EN IEC 62368-1
  - EN 50665
- Art.3.1b EMC:

  - EN 301 489-1
  - EN 301 489-17 (Broadband Wireless)
- Art.3.2 Efficient use of Radio spectrum:

  - EN 300 328
- Art.3.3 Special characteristics

  - N/A

My question is, am I missing something important? Or is it enough? Should other directives or harmonized standards be applied?

Comment: Looking at the certification documents for each of the devices should give a hint as to what standards apply. Note even with CE verified items, the system still needs to comply. CE + CE != CE

Comment: Exactly, that's why they asked us. I told them that certified components do not mean certified products. In this case, for example, a simple bad connection between the components could create a new risk. But what I'm not sure is that if they test their product to the same standards as the certified components, it would be sufficient for their product to provide a presumption of conformity. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> His product falls under the scope of the RED, as it is a radio equipment. According to this directive (paragraph 7 and 8), the Directives of Low Voltage (2014/35/EU) and EMC (2014/30/EU) should not apply to radio equipment (because the RED already covers both Directives).

It's rather that the RED directive covers the EMC directive. But in case of the LVD directive it should be applied to all products where RED applies, ignoring the normal scope of LVD only applying to products with supply >50VAC or >75VDC. This is all a bureaucratic mess - because when chasing down harmonized standards you have to check 3 different lists: for RED, EMC and LVD.

In your case you have 240VAC so LVD applies regardless - so you need to explicitly state conformance to RED and LVD both in the EC declaration of conformity. But you don't need to mention the EMC directive since that's covered by RED.

In practice LVD means that some electrical safety standards could apply, as well as environment standards like IP class.

> Art.3.1a Health & Safety:
> EN IEC 62368-1
> EN 50665

These may apply at some extent (under LVD). Particularly if this is a commercial electronics product and you have reason to believe it may affect people's health (like for example a Bluetooth headset etc might).

> EN 301 489-1
> EN 301 489-17 (Broadband Wireless)

EN 301 489-1 (under EMC) will apply as that's your EMC standard. Likely also part 3 (specific requirements for Short Range Devices). I have no experience with part 17. I'd verify this with a radio/EMC test house.

> EN 300 328

Yes, this would be the radio standard (under RED). Assuming that the module only works on 2.4GHz and not also some sub-GHz bands, because then you have to add some more standards to the list.

---

Note that some of these are EN/ETSI standards (and available for free online, actually), and in those cases you also need to check in the RED and EMC Directive summary list of harmonized standards which exact ETSI version that is normative. Because ETSI often has a newer version available which is to be regarded as a draft, not necessarily to be implemented.

From what I can tell, the current versions are:

- EN/ETSI 301 489-1 V1.9.2
- EN/ETSI 300 328 V2.2.2

It is very important to state the version, as these often come with very different technical requirements. This happened in particular during 2014-2016 when RED was released and lots of standards had their technical contents revised.

I can't find EN 301 489-3 or EN 301 489-17 so maybe these are just referenced from EN 301 489-1. Regardless, you need to know the exact ETSI version. Again, check this with some expert at a test house.

---

> My question is, am I missing something important?

Yes, the whole RoHS directive. It's mandatory for CE marking of all electronic products. The relevant standard is EN/IEC 62321. This is mostly about keeping record of what components you put inside the product and then rely on their manufacturer claiming RoHS compliance.

You also need compliance to WEEE if you put any electronic products on the market. This isn't addressed in CE marking far as I know, but is needed for each country in EU where you put the product on market, you need to have some arrangement for electric recycling. The rules for this change constantly - I'm not up to date with them. You also need to brand your product with the correct "crossed garbage bin", the one with a fat line beneath it is the current one.

Other things that may or may not apply:

Where is the antenna? Is it located on the CE marked module or is an external antenna one explicitly listed as tested by the module manufacturer? If you use a custom antenna, you have made radical changes to the product.

Chargers need to use a standardized interface such as USB-C. As per the RED Directive, commercial electronics are no longer allowed to use manufacturer-specific chargers. This was mainly aimed towards mobile phones and similar mass produced products, it doesn't apply to industrial products and I would assume not to agriculture products either.

Where is the electronics located and could it be exposed to rain or other forms water? Then cabinets need to be IPx5 proof or better, as per EN/IEC 60529.

Does the item controlled by the valve have any moving parts that could harm people or animals? If so, you are suddenly within the scope of the Machinery directive as well. If so, using Arduino becomes a big problem for you since the software libs for it are completely unsuitable for safety-related applications.

Is there a user interface like a control panel/buttons or other similar thing that would put human fingers in close proximity to the device during normal use? If so, then ESD standards apply, EN 61000-6-2.

Comment: Thank you Lundin. What is still not clear to me is if the charger they use already has CE, is it necessary to re-test the entire product under the LVD? I didn't mention RoHS (because its scope and form of compliance was quite clear), but u are absolutely right and thanks for the reminder. About the antenna, environment and buttons I did not take into account, and I will ask the manufacturer. I'm also trying to understand the ETSI guideline (ETSI EG 203 367) for non-radio combined with a radio product and see if it is possible to re-use the existing assessment from its CE certified components.

Comment: @TiagoRibeiro It should suffice to use the CE of the charger if you didn't change anything related to the 240VAC -> 12VDC conversion. However, you still need to carry out the applicable EMC tests on the product as whole and that also covers the charger. Test houses usually type in the exact charger/adapter used in your test report, so the down side of not designing it yourself is that after EMC test you are "married" to the charger/adapter and can't change it later. As for combining radio with non-radio, it's pretty certain that you'll have to do a new CE declaration.

Comment: @TiagoRibeiro As in, you don't necessarily need to do a new test at a test house, since RED offers ways of self-certification. However, both the antenna and the enclosure used are critical EMC/radio components, so it's very questionable to lean on CE marking of individual existing components while changing the antenna and/or enclosure.